# Simplify the function of x

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, limits-without-lhopital

I am given $$ f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to  \infty } (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)...((1+x^{2^n})$$ where $|x| <1$
I think maybe we may apply squeeze theorem here to simplify expression  so I took log of the function 
$$ln(f(x))= ln(1+x)+ln(1+x^2)+ln(1+x^4)+...+ln(1+x^{2^n})$$
I don't know how to proceeded now

Comment: What is the question exactly, are you supposed to show convergence, or supposed to find the value?

Comment: I need to simplify the function in terms of x , answer is given to be 1/1-x  . I mean to simply evaluate the limit

Comment: @Tesla: If the answer is supposed to be $\frac1{1-x}$, then I think the product needs to be $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})\cdots$$ with just powers of $2$ in the exponents. The product given in the question is $$\frac1{1-x} \frac1{1-x^3} \frac1{1-x^5} \frac1{1-x^7}\cdots\frac1{1-x^{2n+1}}\cdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: take $f(x)=f(x)\cdot\dfrac{1-x}{1-x}$

Comment: Simply awesome , you saved the day

Comment: But please, don't use $*$ for multiplication. That is the symbol for *convolution*. (I fixed it for you.)

Comment: Oh k, I don't know what convolution is though, but thanks for d info, I'll keep In mind

Comment: Convolution is something like this: $f*g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)\,dt$.

Comment: There can only be one avz.

Comment: To me, this answer looks right if the question were about the limit of $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})$. What am I missing?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Yes, I just commented that to the question since the OP states the answer is supposed to be $\frac1{1-x}$.